# Can I get Jenkins to use "git clean -ffdx" rather than "git clean -fdx"

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins has "Clean before checkout", which runs `git clean -fdx` before beginning the build. This is not enough.

Can I get it to use `git clean -ffdx` instead?

Comment: How does your pipeline script look like ?

Comment: Not using pipelines

Comment: Would adding a pipeline script be an option ?

Comment: No. At that point, I can just add `git clean -ffdx` to my Makefile's `jenkins` target.